# Why do I get the memory access violation error using pointer to pointer

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I created a small program in C to test pointer to pointer.

When I use a function (line 39) to print a list data, after adding an item to the list I get error 3221225477. However, when I comment the line 39, and I remove the comment from line 59 the program works normally.

Why do I get a ACCESS_VIOLATION error from the operating system, in this case Windows, if the program is running from top to bottom?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>


struct employee{
    int id;
    char name[50];
    char street[50];
};

typedef struct element* List;

struct element{
    struct employee data;
    struct element *next;
};

typedef struct element Elem;

List* list_create();
void  list_print(List* list);
int   list_is_empty(List* list);
int   list_add(List* list, struct employee a);

int main(){

    List* list = list_create();

    struct employee a1;
    a1.id = 10;
    strcpy(a1.name, "John");
    strcpy(a1.street, "Address XYZ");

    list_add(list, a1);
   //Sleep(5000); small pause, I thinking it might have something to do with thread.    

  //list_print(list);   // *****line--39 *****;

    return 0;

}

List* list_create(){
    List* li = (List *) malloc(sizeof(List));
    if(li != NULL)
        *li = NULL;
    return li;
}

int  list_add(List* list, struct employee emp){

        Elem* n1 = (Elem *) malloc(sizeof(Elem));
        n1->data = emp;
        n1->next = *list;
        list = &n1;

        list_print(list);    // *****line--59 *****;

}

void list_print(List* list){

    Elem aux = **list;
    printf(" **lista Id:   %d\n", aux.data.id);
    printf(" **lista name: %s\n", aux.data.name);
    printf(" **lista name: %s\n", aux.data.street);

}
```

Comment: The first thing you should do is stop typedefing pointers. Remove this `typedef struct element* List;` and write everything in terms of `element*` and `element**`. Perhaps some of the errors will become more apparent.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks, I'll review the code and change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C is pass-by-value, not pass-by-reference. Thus, the `List* list` in the function `list_add` and the `List* list` in `main` refer to two different locations in memory (they initially point to the same place at the start of `list_add`, but they are two different pointers with initially the same value, not the same pointer): modifying the value of the variable `list` within `list_add` does not affect the value of `list` in `main`.

To be specific:

`list = &n1` in `list_add` modifies only the value of `list` within that function, i.e. the argument value that was copied into `list_add`'s stack frame on invocation. However, when you try to print it on line 59, still within `list_add`, the changed value is seen and is thus the pointer printed from, working as you expect.

When you try to print `list` on line 39, in `main`, on the other hand, the variable `list` within the `main` function did not have its value changed by the assignment `list = &n1` just before line 39 in `list_add`, since that only changed the value of the copy in that function's scope. Thus in that case `list_print` tries to print elements of an empty list (since the value of `list` is still just what was returned by `list_create`, which is a pointer to a `NULL` pointer, and so `Elem aux = **list` thus dereferences `list` and then tries to dereference a `NULL` pointer) and thus leads to an invalid memory access.

The problem in this code, then, is not the placement of the list's printing but rather that `list_add` is not updating the list properly. In fixing this you need to take into account that it can only modify the list structure by modifying what the reference value it received as an argument is pointing to, rather than by trying to modify the pointer itself. If you do want to modify the address `list` points to in `main` from within the function `list_add` (such as what the line `list = &n1` seems to be attempting to do), you would need to pass a pointer to `list` into `list_add`, rather than just the pointer `list` itself.

There appear to be other issues in the code itself (`list_print` prints only one element and has no handling for printing empty lists, for example, which is what causes the error here to be an actual invalid memory access instead of merely incorrectly leaving the list empty after calling `list_add`), but the issue described above is the cause of this particular problem.

Comment: I really did not mind the copy of data by function. The confusion was precisely because it's using pointers to pointers. As for the list of errors in empty list, I left out to leave the code smaller. Thank you very much! His answer was accurate and enlightening.